# How to avoid multiple instance of a bot in Discord server

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I created a bot to run on a private server. This bot checks the current datetime and gives commands at specific hours.
I experienced in a previous version of the bot multiple disconnections which appeared to be caused by a discord problem. My solution was then to set a cron command to relaunch the bot every hour, just in case it crashed previously. Now, my bot is running perfectly but it seems I have multiple instances of the bot in the server, since every message is sent 4 or 5 times.

Is there a mean to chec if the node server is already active or if the bot is already logged in ?

The cron :
`00 * * * * cd C:/Users/[...]/bot/ && node bootstrap.js`

The bot constructor :

````
    let self = this;

    this.file = './env/env_'+pEnv+'.json';

    //Env file
    let tmpData = _FS.readFileSync(this.file);  
    this.params = JSON.parse(tmpData);

    //Timer setup
    this.interval = setInterval(function(){self.checkTimer();},1000);

    //Discord client launch
    this.client = new _DISCORD.Client();
    this.client.login(pToken);
    this.client.on('ready', () => {
        self.init();
    });
    self.client.on('message', (pMessage) => {
       self.reacts(pMessage);
    });
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `cron` to run every hour which will execute a new instance every hour, even if there was already an instance(s) running. I recommend using
[Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to ensure the app restarts upon closing.

You can run it with `forever start app.js` and it'll give you what you're after.

Comment: this seems really fine, it secures an app crash. But what about a power shortage ? With cron, I'm assured the command will run itself again. If I pu a Forever command in a cron, will it run multiple instances ?

Comment: Forever just restarts if the process is closed so there most likely will never be more than one instance of the bot. I recommend dropping cron completely though. Your actually problem is that cron is running every hour which will just keep making new instances every hour. Try just using `forever start app.js` and see if it helps.

Comment: @MichaelMaurel You can just do a crontab of `@reboot forever start app.js` which will start the bot when the server boots up. This handles both power failures and app crashes.

Comment: So...  

I tried to create a simple file with the @reboot just to check if the syntax was accepted, and it worked. I then tried the two following solutions without success : first, directly in the cron : `@reboot sleep 30 && cd /home/me/[...] && forever start myScript.js` ; secondly, with a sh file (the file works when called manually) : `@reboot /home/me/[...]/doOnReboot.sh`

Comment: found the solution. The cron calls the .sh script, but in order for it to work, I called the complete path.  
[cron] :  `@reboot /home/me/Documents/doOnReboot.sh`  // [script] : `cd /home/me/[...]/ && /usr/local/bin/forever start myScript.js`